# How to delete all security groups on Amazon ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've created new EC2 spot requests over the last weeks. A new security group was created for every request. When the spot requests were deleted the security groups were not deleted. I've hit the 100 groups limit and want to delete them. The EC2 interface apparently allows only one deletion at a time, which means I would have to make 300 clicks to delete these groups. Or is there a better way to delete multiple security groups with few clicks or lines of code?

Answer (score 4):

THis would need some basic scripting and AWS SDK. you can do this with pretty much all the SDK provided by AWS.

I would prefer `AWS-CLI` as i already have it installed and configured. This is what I would do:

1. list all the SGs with [describe-security-groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html)
2. Install [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/linux32/jq) (the Json parser for BASH)
3. Pull the SG IDs (check [this](http://xmodulo.com/2013/05/how-to-parse-json-string-via-command-line-on-linux.html) for `jq` syntax)
4. Once you have the SG IDs, run [delete-security-group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/delete-security-group.html) by usig a `for` loop.

This is fairly simple and straight forward way of doing wat you want to do. THis can be done by any of the AWS SDKs.

These are just a couple of commands which can be constructed into a Bash script, provided:

1. You have [aws-cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html) installed and configured
2. you have `jq` installed on your system.

If you already have some other AWS SDK installed, then you are better off with that as java/python/ruby...etc all have their own inbuilt way of parsing JSON/HASH/DataStructure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not this simple. Security groups often reference one another so this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by combining a command that lists all security groups and one other that deletes them.

If you are using the python `boto` API (for example) that would be:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_ec2(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
groups = conn.get_all_security_groups()
```

Which returns (as an example): `[SecurityGroup:appserver, SecurityGroup:default, SecurityGroup:vnc, SecurityGroup:webserver]`

And then you delete them all:

```
for group in groups:
    conn.delete_security_group(group.split(":")[1])
```

**Edit**

You should run the commands on your shell.

Comment: Have tried your solution, but the current instances cannot access the older security groups, only two are listed, the one being used and the default one. I cannot do it this way because the instances where the security groups were used have been terminated days ago. The current instances run all on only 1 new security group (I've learned from my mistakes). So apparently I will have to click freaking 300 times. If I select more than one security group the ec2 UI disables the delete button. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Casady " I cannot do it this way because the instances where the security groups were used have been terminated days ago" I'm not really in your cloud but I can't understand what this means. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought `get_all_security_groups` gets all  security groups. :) You should try @slayedbylucifer 's answer too.

Comment: I thought so too! But I've logged in to one of the instances, run the python scrypt and it displays only two. The one created for the instance, and the default one.

Comment: @Casady You shouldn't do it from an instance :)  Do it on your shell and your pc  and it will work.

Comment: Did it on my own PC using this scrypt: https://gist.github.com/miketheman/2630437 Put in my own keys and run it from a local PC. I get this output: root@ubuntu:~/ec2/2630437# ./security-group-cleanup.py: [u'default', u'nv1'] -- so still only 2 groups are displayed, but 98 do exist in my ec2 control panel.
The list of security groups to be removed is below.
Run this again with `--delete` to remove them
[u'default', u'nv1']
Total of 2 groups targeted for removal.

Answer (score 0):

These solutions only work if you don't have rules in *other* security groups that reference the security groups in question.  I have a couple scripts that will delete a single security group, including the ingress rules in other security groups.  I also handle the special case of ingress rules referencing the AWS ELB default security group.  If you have this more complex situation, the solutions above won't delete your security group because of these other rules.  My scripts are here (one for ec2-classic and one for VPC based security groups):  https://gist.github.com/arpcefxl/2acd7d873b95dbebcd42

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void delete(List<String> sgs) {
    AmazonEC2Client ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(Credentials.getCredentialsProvider());
    ec2.setEndpoint("ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"); // default

    for(String sg:sgs) {
        System.out.println("DELETING SECURITY GROUP " + sg);
        DeleteSecurityGroupRequest delReq = new DeleteSecurityGroupRequest().withGroupName(sg);
        try {
            ec2.deleteSecurityGroup(delReq);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```